# Excel: if item is in column A and NOT in column B then populate column C with item from column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How do you do this in excel? I see a lot of complicated answers involving the MATCH function but it just returns the position of that value - I want column C to populate with the items that are found in column A but NOT column B. Sorry if this is totally a repeat question but the answers I've found on this site really confuse me. if someone could even link me to a helpful answer that already exists I'd appreciate it

Comment: Put this into column C: =IF(iserror(match(item,A:A,0))=false,IF(iserror(match(item,B:B,0))= true, "match","not match"),"not match")

Comment: Replace "item" with whatever you are searching from, "match" with whatever you want to return if your conditions are true, and "not match" with whatever you want to appear when not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C1 put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)))/(COUNTIF($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("ZZZ",$B:$B)),$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)))=0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Then copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario as above except instead of A-Z items, I have numbers from 1-3500 that I am trying to put in column C, and this formula does not work for that. Could someone give me that formula, or tell me how to change this one so it will work for me please? Thank you for your genius advice in advance!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1216780)